# RecyclerView is cutting off the last item when switching to landscape mode

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am using `TabLayout` in the `MainActivity`, in the second `tab` i have a `RecyclerView` inside it, i successfully bind data to `RecyclerView`, everything is Ok, but when i rotate screen to Landscape Mode the last item of the Recycler is getting cutt-off,

this how the problem looks like:

**This is in the portrait mode :**

[image]

**and the Landscape mode :**

[image]

And this is my XML Files :

**Fragment Layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cities_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**and finally the RecyclerView Item :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_city"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxHeight="250dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

i tried to add `android:layout_marginBottom` to de RecyclerView but is not working.

thanks.

Comment: Have you only one xml for root view (view tablayout) for landscape and for portrait mode?

Comment: Yes, i have only one.

Comment: use a scrollview with a linear layout childview... to wrap  up the recyclerview...or give margin to the bottom of recyckerview

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: Why do you need `android:scrollbars="none"`? Looks to me like there isn't enough space for your items on screen, and because you can't scroll it looks like the View is getting "cut off".

Comment: Looks like layout for fragment have all height on landscape and height without tabbar on portrait mode. Can you give me apk?

Comment: i just changed the fragment xml Layout to Relativelayout with paddingBottom= 47dp, it works, but i think it is not a good solution as long as i don't know the  origin of the pronlem

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"/>

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
android:id="@+id/cities_recycler_view" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:scrollbars="none" 
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
android:layout_marginStart="5dp" 
android:layout_marginEnd="5dp" 
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf ="parent"
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add a static height of 250dp to the cardview or to relative layout of recyclerview item

Comment: Try by changing constraint layout to linear layout

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem right now while developing an application for a tablet and it's so annoying there is no answer for this, I have found 2 solutions.

I don't think they are good at all.

First you can either provide a bottom padding like 150dp or create a view at the end of your layout with a height of 150dp.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the links to these two _not so good solutions_ after all and let the OP try them

Comment: I did tell him how he can replicate the solutions "First you can either provide a bottom padding like 150dp or create a view at the end of your layout with a height of 150dp.", believe me, those are basic things and everyone working on android knows how to do them that's why I didn't write the code for it.